# Android Studio не видит viewBinding

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio не видит viewBinding, если не подсвечивает его фиолетовым, не предлагает его в подсказках? Или все-таки видит - как это проверить? [[image: viewBinding серого цвета][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBwrn.png)

Comment: Я вообще не припомню чтобы подсказки когда-либо работали для AGP. У вас по пути `<project>/<module>/build/generated/` должна появиться папка `data_binding_что-то_там` с классами биндинга, если ни после синхронизации проекта, ни после ребилда она не появилась - тогда надо искать причину.